# Tabbing through input fields doesn't add class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form where when you click into a field the label will shrink and move to the top of the input field allowing the user to then enter a value.

It works perfectly fine unless you tab through the fields, and then you get the issue of the label not moving up.

This is the JS I am using when a user clicks onto an input field

```js
$(document).on("click", ".js-form-item", function() {
  $(this).addClass('form-item--input-filled');
});

$(document).on("blur", ".form-item__input", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $(this).parent('.js-form-item').removeClass('form-item--input-filled');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item--with-scaling-label js-form-item form-item form-item-textfield">
  <label class="form-item__label">School Name</label>
  <input required="" type="text" ng-model="model.enquiry.SchoolName" class="form-text form-item__input ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="SchoolName">
</div>
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Please add your CSS. And have you tried `.on("focus"` instead of `.on("click"`?

Comment: change the event from `click` to `focus`. Btw, no need for `JavaScript` as `CSS` can do it for you.

Comment: @j08691 .on("focus" worked a treat - thank you!

Comment: Since you are using jquery you can try with the methods focusin() and focusout()

Answer (score 0):

In your case you will need to use **focus()** and **focusout()** functions and detect the **js-form-item** as parent().
Try this:

```
// This will add the class on input focus
$('.form-text').focus( function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass('form-item--input-filled');
});

// This will remove the class on input focus
$('.form-text').focusout( function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('form-item--input-filled');
});
```

Let me know if this helped. Regards.